# How to do a log out [iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 2 ViewControllers. After login it will move to the next screen. Then one logout button will be appear. After user press log out button it should return to login screen with an empty text field.

How would I do that? I tried all ways, but it doesn't seem to work.

My first ViewController:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sampleDictionary = @{@"username":@"alex", @"password":@"1234"};
}

- (IBAction)loginTapped
{
    if ([self.sampleDictionary[@"password"] isEqualToString:passwordField.text]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ss" sender:self];
    } else {
        // Alert message
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"wrong" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:actionOk];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

This is my second ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}

- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: So where is the problem? It doesn't go back? The fields are not empty? Or what...

Comment: log out is not working

Comment: How is it not working? What is not happening what suppose is to happen?

Comment: after enter login it will move to next screen.in that next screen when i press logout button ,it not return to login screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *logoutButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 50)];
    [logoutButton setTitle:@"Log Out" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [logoutButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [logoutButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [logoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logout) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:logoutButton];
}

- (void)logout
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `ViewController` remove the text for username and password fields in viewWillAppear.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    usernameField.text = @"";
    passwordField.text = @"";
}
```

Comment: if we did @"" for both text field.then how we will login with user name/password for login

Comment: Once you logged out your textfields will be empty by above code. User again den enter their credential to login.